# Add function to an event?

Tags: c#, vb.net, function, events

A friend of mine gave me a project in C#, but I needed it on VB.Net, so I started to translate it.
But there was a line that's a little bit akward, and I can't translate (neither does him).

```
LBTelemetry.Data += LBTelemetry_Data;
```

This is the source code from the DLL that concerns it:

```
public delegate void TelemetryData(LBTelemetry_A data, bool useTimestamp);

 public class LBTelemetry
 {
    public event TelemetryData Data;
    //...
 }
```

Is there a way to translate it into VB.Net?
Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data types of that line are not clear, but it looks like it might be adding an event handler, which you can do like this:

```
AddHandler LBTelemetry.Data, LBTelemetry_Data
```

Comment: Exactly! Aybe did post the documentation link here, and was able to translate from it.